# Populate ListView with ArrayList created in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am trying to populate my listView with the "name" field of my ArrayList. The ArrayList is being created with JSON data. The listView is being populated when I add an object to the ArrayList in the onCreate method, but the values added within the doInBackground are not showing up. I can see the data being created properly. I believe I need to pass the ArrayList back to the Main Activity class, but I have tried different variations and can't seem to figure it out. Also, I am using an object array as I will need to utilize the other fields later on in my project. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Character> characterArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView theList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        theList.setAdapter(adapter = new myAdapter());


        CharacterGetData characterGetData = new CharacterGetData();
        characterGetData.execute();
    }

//Character Class
class Character{
       String name;
       String height;
       String mass;

       public Character(String name, String height, String mass){
           this.name=name;
           this.height=height;
           this.mass=mass;
       }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getMass() {
        return mass;
    }

    public void setMass(String mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }
}
//GET CHARACTER DATA, CREATE OBJECTS
    class CharacterGetData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String name;
        String height;
        String mass;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            URL obj = new URL("https://swapi.dev/api/people/?format=json");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);

            }
            in.close();

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject characterObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                name = characterObj.getString("name");
                height = characterObj.getString("height");
                mass = characterObj.getString("mass");
                Character character1 = new Character(name,height,mass);
                characterArray.add(character1);
                Log.i("MainActivity", "The name is " + character1.name + "the height is " + character1.height);
            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}



    class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return characterArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Character getItem(int position) {
            return characterArray.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View old, ViewGroup parent) {
            View newView =old;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            if(newView==null){
                newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item,parent,false);
            }
            TextView textview= newView.findViewById(R.id.character_name_textview);
            //Here get a name
            textview.setText(getItem(position).name);

            return newView;
        }
    }

 }
```

LAYOUT FILES:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>



  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/character_name_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything seems find in debugging aswell.
DEBUGGER:

```
06/23 15:29:25: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 227 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.androidlabs/com.example.androidlabs.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.androidlabs
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.androidlabs
Connected to process 17374 on device 'Pixel_4_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Connecting to com.example.androidlabs
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:62702', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10154(com.example.androidlabs) identical 5 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1478)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/ple.androidlab: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ple.androidlab: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xea49fb90, tid 17399
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xea4a0300: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea4a0300: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbbb74cf0) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xea4a16b0, tid 17399
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f3ffe000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/MainActivity: The name is Luke Skywalkerthe height is 172
I/MainActivity: The name is C-3POthe height is 167
I/MainActivity: The name is R2-D2the height is 96
I/MainActivity: The name is Darth Vaderthe height is 202
I/MainActivity: The name is Leia Organathe height is 150
I/MainActivity: The name is Owen Larsthe height is 178
I/MainActivity: The name is Beru Whitesun larsthe height is 165
I/MainActivity: The name is R5-D4the height is 97
I/MainActivity: The name is Biggs Darklighterthe height is 183
I/MainActivity: The name is Obi-Wan Kenobithe height is 182
```

Comment: Use RecyclerView instead of ListView it is more efficient and much faster than listview.

Comment: I appreciate that, it's a school assignment, so it was specific in which methods I needed to use. Its good to know though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to anyone struggling with the same issue:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Character> characterArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        CharacterGetData characterGetData = new CharacterGetData();
        characterGetData.execute();
    }

//Character Class
class Character{
       String name;
       String height;
       String mass;

       public Character(String name, String height, String mass){
           this.name=name;
           this.height=height;
           this.mass=mass;
       }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getMass() {
        return mass;
    }

    public void setMass(String mass) {
        this.mass = mass;
    }
}
//GET CHARACTER DATA, CREATE OBJECTS
    class CharacterGetData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    ListView theList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String resultData="";
        try {

            URL obj = new URL("https://swapi.dev/api/people/?format=json");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);

            }
            in.close();
            resultData = response.toString();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          return resultData;


        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject characterObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

              String  name = characterObj.getString("name");
              String  height = characterObj.getString("height");
              String  mass = characterObj.getString("mass");
            Character character1 = new Character(name,height,mass);
            characterArray.add(character1);
            Log.i("MainActivity", "The name is " + character1.name + "the height is " + character1.height);
            theList.setAdapter(adapter = new myAdapter());
        }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```